# How to use Awk command in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, awk, svn

```
public class CmdHelper
{
    public static string StartCmd(string commandLine)
    {
    commandLine = commandLine.Trim().TrimStart('&') + "&exit";
    string outputMsg = "";
    Process pro = new Process();
    pro.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    pro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    pro.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    pro.Start();
    pro.StandardInput.WriteLine(commandLine);
    pro.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;
    pro.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    pro.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    outputMsg += pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    pro.WaitForExit();
    pro.Close();

    return outputMsg;
}

public static void CommitBundleToSvn()
{
    string folderPath = EditorConst.BundlesPath + VEngine.Editor.Builds.Settings.GetPlatformName();
    string command = "svn status " + folderPath;
    string regaxPattern = ".*&exit";
    string output = "";
    string[] regexRes = {};
    command = "svn st " + folderPath+ " | awk \"{if ($1 == \\\"?\\\") {print $2} }\""; 
    output = CmdHelper.StartCmd(command);
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(command);
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(output);
}
```

Execute command:

```
("svn st " + folderPath+ " | awk \"{if ($1 == \\\"?\\\") {print $2} }\"")
```

In `windows cmd`, cmd could get return message.

Now I call the CommitBundleToSvn(). but the cmd will not exit.

If the command is "svn status " + folderPath, it is expected.

Comment: try switching the `awk` encapsulator to single quote and see if it works : `... | awk '{if ($1 == \"?\") {print $2} }' ")`

Comment: Not, using single quote in cmd is failed.  but in powerShell is successed

Comment: Show the window see what’s going on. Work from there

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to not use `awk` in this case, and do:

```
command = "svn st " + folderPath+ ";
output = CmdHelper.StartCmd(command);
output = string.Join("\r\n", output.Split("\r\n",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(x => x.Split(' ',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]
    .Contains("?"))
    .Select(s => s.Split(' ',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1])
    .ToList());
```